# Sympy substitute in fractions won't work as expected

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

Simpy is not detecting basic substitions with subs.

I have the following fraction:

```
d₂⋅n₁⋅n₂
──────── + m₂⋅n₁ + mm₂⋅n₂
   nc
─────────────────────────
            nc
```

Written as

```
cm2 = (d2*n1*n2/nc + m2*n1 + mm2*n2)/nc
```

Now I want to replace n1/nc = np1 and n2/nc = np2. So I've written:

`cm2.subs({n1/nc : symbols("np1"), n2/nc: symbols("np2")})`

The result is:

```
d₂⋅n1p⋅n₂ + m₂⋅n₁ + mm₂⋅n₂
──────────────────────────
            nc
```

Instead I expected that sympy would figure out the other substitutions and output:

```
d2⋅n1p⋅n2p + m2⋅n1p + mm2⋅n2p
```

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`subs` is mostly literal, so after the first substitution, say `n1/nc->n1p`, then `n2/nc` no longer appears and so it cannot be replaced. But it's not necessary to do the re-arrangement of expressions to get them in the form needed to make the substitution, you can use `solve` to resolve everything for you:

```
>>> eqs
(Eq(cm2, (d2*n1*n2/nc + m2*n1 + mm2*n2)/nc), Eq(n1/nc, np1), Eq(n2/nc, np2))
>>> solve(eqs,cm2,n1,n2, dict=True)
[{cm2: d2*np1*np2 + m2*np1 + mm2*np2, n1: nc*np1, n2: nc*np2}]
```

There is also an unimplemented feature described [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2720#issuecomment-312437508) that offers, perhaps, a more intuitive way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Sympy's `subs` can have troubles converting an expression by another expression, especially if they don't appear literally in the source expression. It also can be quite ambiguous.

When the goal is that all `n1` and `n2` disappear from `cm2`, the substitution can be written differently:

```py
from sympy import symbols

d2, n1, n2, nc, m2, mm2, n = symbols("d2 n1 n2 nc m2 mm2 n")
np1, np2 = symbols("np1 np2")
cm2 = (d2 * n1 * n2 / nc + m2 * n1 + mm2 * n2) / nc
cm2.subs({n1: np1 * nc, n2: np2 * nc}).simplify()
```

Result: `d2*np1*np2 + m2*np1 + mm2*np2`